# Google play storelisting: You need fix your high-res icon. It is not a valid image

Tags: icons, google-play, png, paint.net

Okay, so while trying to upload my 512x512 app icon on google play, it comes up with the error: You need to fix your high-res icon. It is not a valid image.

I saw another post about this, but the solution was to save it in pain.net, which mine was created in! It is a png file, and fits the measurments:

[image]

Any ideas why it comes up with this error?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "pain.net" sounds really painful. Check your PNG with [`pngcheck`](http://png-mng.sourceforge.net/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) or a similar tool.

Comment: @Jongware what do you mean painful?

Comment: WARNING: No color-space metadata and no embedded color profile: -- http://regex.info/exif.cgi?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FdkS7m.png  -- Images for the web are most widely viewable when in the sRGB color space                     so reformat it as (color profile: “sRGB”)

Comment: @Tasos how do I reformat it?

Comment: you have photoshop? if you dont have it download gimp https://www.gimp.org/ and check here how to convert to srgb color space https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-imaging-color-management.html

Comment: I dont understand how to convert to srgb @Tasos

Comment: check on youtube how to --- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDmsuUg8T8I

Answer (score 4):

Playstore says: 512 x 512 - 32-bit PNG (with alpha)
In graphics, alpha means there should be background color. Playstore doesn't accept transparent icons.
So solution is to make a background color of it.
Another solution is convert it to JPEG.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to upload my icon after "Saving for Web..." in Photoshop as a PNG24 with a transparent background.  Uploading a PNG8 version produced the error you mentioned.